# LESS & automatic CSS cacheing

Tags: javascript, css, caching, automation, less

I'm interested in using a css preprocessor and am leaning towards LESS. I'm proficient at writing CSS myself, but want to take advantage of a few of the dynamic features. I'm not positive that adding constant extra steps in production (like compiling) are worth the benefit though.

I like LESS because I can use less.js to compile client-side (during development only), is there a tool out there though that would automatically detect the timestamp on my less file and compile it to css and overwrite the current css file? I'd love to achieve this level of transparency so I could worry about the code and less about compiling it and refreshing... Something similar to http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/ but combining a compiler with it? If not Is anyone interested in helping build it?

Comment: If you are interested in a PHP solution, this is a guide on automatic compilation of LESS files, all you need to do is reference your LESS file like you would a CSS file in the `<head>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274628/compile-less-css-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less.js will already recompile if the source has changed -- I have never had an issue with it being stale during development. I did end up switching to a compile-on-save workflow using textmate's less bundle though wince switching out link tags before deployment and testing was getting annoying.

That being said I'm sure you could wire up something to watch the file on disk and invoke the node.js lessc compiler.

UPDATE TO CLARIFY DEV CYCLE:

During development I include the less.js file in the page and link to my `styles.less` file via `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less>`

When I push out to production I change that to:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`

But, during development, every time I save the `styles.less` file, I use a TextMate bundle to also compile down a `styles.css` file, so the change out is a matter of commenting/uncommenting in my source file.

I have the bundle set to use node.js lessc compiler with `--compress` set so it gives you a nice compact stylesheet.

Comment: I wasn't aware that less.js would recompile if source changed. I didn't see or notice that in the documentation

Comment: If you're including the js file in your HTML along with a link with the appropriate type, then yes!

Comment: I see, the trick is to use the js compiler during development and then  a client side compiler (or copy/paste the style tag) to make a static css file to server on the production site. I wasn't grasping the full workflow picture.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show how I do my development cycle

Answer (score 2):

This simple function do it :

```
less.autoRefresh = function(time)
{
    var sheets = [];
    for(var i = less.sheets.length; i--; )
        sheets.push(less.sheets[i].href);
    setInterval(
        function() 
        {
            for(var i = sheets.length; i--; )
                less.sheets[i].href = sheets[i] + '?'+Math.random();

            less.refresh(1);
        }, 
        time || 1000
    );

    var fnImport = less.tree.Import;
    less.tree.Import = function(path, imports)
    {
        path.value += '?x='+Math.random();
        fnImport(path, imports);
    }
}
less.autoRefresh(2000);
```

Will refresh every 2000 ms the less files. It doesn't check headers, etc... but should do in dev env.

Comment: wow, Thanks! 

I'll look into this as well. It sounds like less.js has this built in already? I'm hoping to set it so that my css is auto compiled server-side and saved, then my html files will not even need to access the less files. They'll just pull in the latest css.

Comment: It was not built-in but less.js is (in my opinion) well coded. So... i just had to add a setInterval and force sheets and imports to be reloaded by adding some random in the href and refresh all. - I have to add ( i read your others comment ) This is for dev env, it don't compile and write a css file. Like less.js in client side, it just recompile the differents files in javascript and write the result in a "style" tag

Answer (score 0):

There is [SimpLess](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) (free, available for Linux, Mac, Windows), I haven't used it myself, but I'm looking forward to integrating it with my workflow some time in the near future.

Comment: yes, but this is an additional program I have to keep and run locally. I'm not a fan of the workflow of editing a .less file and having it (even automatically) compile into a css file which I then have to upload to view edits (I'm not working locally in this case). I'm wanting something I can edit my file via ftp or anywhere and my css will be generated server-side. I don't want the server to have to generate it for every user though. It should know to save the compiled file as css and server that.